# Save ascii as clear string into txt file

Tags: python

my code:

```
f = open("log.txt", "a")
key = chr(event.Ascii)
f.write(key)
f.closed
```

If I print the key out. I get a nice readable form like "a" "b" "c" and so on.
But i if look into the file python has saved it as ascii - like that: 0013 0200 4461

I tried to convert it but i just get errors. Anybody knows whats wrong here?

Comment: BTW, what's `closed` supposed to do (in your case)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `f.close()` not `f.closed`.

Also, you are putting the key code in key.

If you want to read a single char, you could use:

`sys.stdin.read(1)`

(See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/510404/103081)

Putting it all together:

```
import sys
f = open("log.txt", "a")
key = sys.stdin.read(1)
f.write(key)
f.close()
```

This should be fine for a homework problem or learning python on your own.  For someone writing a keylogger to steal password and credit card numbers, though, this is useless because return must be hit to get the input.

Comment: It was part of my homework for my school. To save an input to a file. :) thanks Paul